# If the Eyrie does not have enough spare warriors to recruit - does this cause turmoil?

Tags: root

In Root if the Eyrie can't resolve the decree they fall in to turmoil.

In the case that the Eyrie have territory that they can recruit on - but already have all their warriors out (this can especially happen with the charismatic leader) - does this count as a turmoil trigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Rule 7.5.2. `If you cannot fully take an action, you immediately fall into turmoil (7.7).`

Comment: Take into account that the Eyrie is designed so it always eventually falls in turmoil and forces a change of leader.

Comment: You say that, but I've seen plenty of games where they never went into turmoil, and even a few where they won without going into turmoil.

Comment: Ok, then I'll say it's easy to fall into turmoil but a skilled player can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes
I don't have a copy of this game, so I can't cite a rule to prove it, but I played it a few weeks ago, and the owner of the game, who also explained it to us, especially pointed out this to the player who played Eyrie, that he should always pay attention on having enough warriors to fulfill the recruiting part of his manifest.